# Printing out 3 of numbers in java

Tags: java

The output value is 100000 to 10 random natural numbers
What should I do to print out only from the right end to the third?
And if you print it out with multiple of ten, an error appears
so, if we get a multiple of 10, i want to put out 010 something

for example, input -> 6545 output -> 545,
input -> 27 output -> 027

and i'm using java.
pls help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your inputs are actually `int`s:

```
System.out.printf("%03d",inputvalue%1000);
```

should give the result you want:

- `"%03d"` forces output with zero padding
- `inputvalue%1000` calculates the remainder of division by 1000 (modulo), which will chop off all digits to the left of the three last

Comment: produces a wrong result for random inputs greater than 4 digits long

Comment: @DereckChamboko and why would that be the case?

Answer (score 1):

You can transform an Int to a String with `String.valueOf(i)`. Then, you only have to take the 3 last characters of the string and adding 0. Because your "027" is a String, it isn't an Int

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String... args) {
  
    Random rand = new Random();
    int upperbound = 100000;
    int lowerbound = 10;
    int random_integer = rand.nextInt(upperbound - lowerbound) + lowerbound;

    String output = String.valueOf(random_integer);
    String finaloutput = output;
    if (output.length() <= 3) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3 - output.length(); i++) {
            finaloutput = "0" + finaloutput;
        }
    } else {
        finaloutput = output.substring(0, 3);
    }

    System.out.println(random_integer + "->" + finaloutput);

}
```

Comment: That seems like a pretty convoluted and slow way of arriving at the goal OP was looking for...